# I installed ros kinetic but it says there's no file directory for bash electric

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, bash, ubuntu, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed Ros KInetic, using ubunto 16.04
But now everytime I open the terminal there's

```
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

and everytime I try using those commands

```
echo "source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
```

I get an identical line in addiction

so now whenever I open the terminal there are 5 lines of it

```
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash: No such file or directory
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/306466/i-installed-ros-kinetic-but-it-says-there%27s-no-file-directory-for-bash-electric/) by [Samah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38163/samah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Electric is of course not ROS Kinetic, so those error messages are to be expected when you have Kinetic installed and not Electric.

To get rid of the errors however, do the following:

```
gedit $HOME/.bashrc
```

now scroll all the way to the end of the file (bottom) and remove all the lines that look like the following:

```
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
```

There should be **five** of those.

---

And could you please tell us where you found instructions to run `echo "source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` after having installed ROS Kinetic? Because that would be incorrect and should be fixed.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Samah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38163/samah/) on 2018-10-23**:
Thank you, it worked.
No, it wasn't during the installation. I had a problem with bash before so I probably copied an answer on a forum that contained electric.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-23**:\

> so I probably copied an answer on a forum that contained electric.

I know it's difficult when you're just starting out, but please always be careful when copy-pasting commands from (old) forum posts. They may no longer be relevant and could actually make things worse.

**Comment by [Samah](https://answers.ros.org/users/38163/samah/) on 2018-10-23**:
Yes, thank you.
and of course I'll keep that in mind.

**Comment by [SANDY](https://answers.ros.org/users/21545/sandy/) on 2020-05-26**:
As you say the above "echo ..." line is incorrect and you would like to know where is it still present. You can still find it for the kinetic ROS at http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu , I have just followed those instructions  and got the error you describe for electric ROS. Thanks for the solution anyway.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-26**:
I don't understand your comment.

The link your mention does not have the word `electric` anywhere on the page, so I'm confused as to how you would get an error mentioning it.